# VBA how use Selectquery to get next match

Tags: vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

The following line will the selected first CSS selector matched, but how do I select next match

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("option[value='2']").Selected = True
```

Html code

```html
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls"><input name="sys_original.incident.impact" id="sys_original.incident.impact" type="hidden" value=""><select name="incident.impact" class="form-control" id="incident.impact" style="direction: ltr;" onchange="onChange('incident.impact');" mandatory="true" ng-non-bindable="true"><option value="">-- None --</option><option value="1">1 - High</option><option value="2">2 - Medium</option><option value="3">3 - Low</option></select></div>
```

The other one

```html
 <div class="form-group is-required" id="element.incident.urgency"><div id="label.incident.urgency" nowrap="true" type="choice" data-type="label" choice="1"><label class=" col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label" dir="ltr" onclick="return labelClicked(this);" for="incident.urgency"><span title="" class="required-marker label_description" id="status.incident.urgency" aria-label="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit" data-original-title="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit" oclass="" mandatory="true"></span><span title="" class="label-text" data-original-title="Measure of the business criticality based on the impact and on the business needs of the Customer" data-html="false">Urgency</span></label></div><div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls"><input name="sys_original.incident.urgency" id="sys_original.incident.urgency" type="hidden" value=""><select name="incident.urgency" class="form-control" id="incident.urgency" style="direction: ltr;" onchange="onChange('incident.urgency');" mandatory="true" ng-non-bindable="true"><option value="">-- None --</option><option value="1">1 - High</option><option value="2">2 - Medium</option><option value="3">3 - Low</option></select></div><div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 form-field-addons"></div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry again on the formating

Comment: Could you provide a wider snapshot of the html please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Getting aNodeList of all elements with option tags in the frame:**

You should be able to get a `nodeList` with using the `querySelectorAll` method of `document`, rather than just `querySelector`.  The CSS pattern would switch from specifying the exact value for the attribute `value` e.g. value='2', to a more general, elements with `option` tag having attribute `value` i.e.

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelectorAll("option[value]")
```

But it looks like this will bring back more nodes than you may require due to multiple dropdowns with `option` tags. It is hard to say without more HTML to test with.

---

**Being more selective:**

Ideally, you want to add in an additional selector to the CSS selector query that narrows this down with an id or className etc that limits to just nodes of interest. Then index into that list, from 0, to set various options.

E.g. for the first of the two selection lists you shown you can isolate with the following CSS selector, to get a nodeList of the possible options:

```
select[id=incident.impact] option
```

**N.B. The second list can be obtained with `select[id=incident.urgency] option`.**

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

So, when you apply the CSS selector with the `.querySelectorAll` method you should get a `nodeList` matching the above elements. You can then access by index:

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
Set aNodeLIst = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelectorAll("select[id=incident.impact] option")

For i = 0 to aNodeList.Length - 1
   Debug.Print aNodeList.item(i).outerHTML
Next i
```

**Select a specific node:**

```
aNodeList.item(2).Selected = True  '<== Medium, as shown in query results image above
```

---

**tl;dr**

If you literally want the next option on from your current, provided you aren't at the end of the list, you can use an adjacent sibling selector of:

```
select[id=incident.urgency] option[value=2] + option
```

Where the + option specifies to select the next element with `option` tag after the element with id `incident.urgency` and `option` tag with attribute `value=2`.

[image: CSS query2]

In this case, it would select option 3  = `Low`.

If you were at option 1, not 2,  it would be `select[id=incident.urgency] option[value=1] + option` etc.

Comment: Set aNodeList = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelectorAll("select[id='incident.impact'] option")

Comment: Sorry., typo... I missed the opening " as you saw. Well spotted.